# POCO Relationship Updates with Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have a model in my `EntityFrameworkCore 2.0` Solution. the Class layout is as follows;

```
public class Trader : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    /*REMOVED FOR BREVITY*/


    public ApplicationUser AccountManager { get; set; }
}
```

Where  `ApplicationUser` is implementing `IdentityUser`;

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity
```

Now I want the ability to update the `AccountManager` periodically as the traders get passed around regularly.

To do this I have the following service method (simplified for brevity);

```
var trader = context.Find<Trader>(traderId);

var user = await userContext.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());

trader.User = user;

context.Save(trader, userName);
```

If I try to do this I get error;

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AspNetUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Which is implying it is trying to insert a new User to the users table. Now the user above exists. as far as I was aware Entity Framework would simply create the relationship if a valid Id was passed into the entity? and if the complex object sent across has a null value for the sub entity would insert a new one?

I could add an additional field of;

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

and set this as an FK to the ApplicationUser in the class, but I was hoping to keep the class minimal? Is this possible or is this the only way to set it? (or can I set something using fluent confrigurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different contexts.

Each context doesn't track all the two entities:

- `trader` instance is tracked by `context` instance.
- `user` instance if tracked by `userContext` instance.

So because you're using `context` in `context.Save(trader, userName);` then one of the following options:

- use that context to retrieve `trader`instance
- use `context.Attach(trader)` before updating `User` property.
- more better add a foreign key property `UserId` on `Trader` class and set that property value like `trader.UserId = user.Id`.

Comment: Ahh, ok, correct I am using `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`, so will EF not see that the `Trader.AccountManager.Id != null` and automatically set its state to be referenced as opposed to insert a new instance (i.e. is .Attach not assumed as default)?

Comment: Yep. That's it. EF only look at `EntityState` enum (`Added`, `Modified` etc). So if you add a new entity to it even if it has an `Id != null` the state will still be `EntityState.Added`